# VSCode Kernel-Doc Documentation Hint

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

My VSCode won't show commented documentation hint as expected. For this code,

```cpp
/**
 * list_add - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it after
 *
 * Insert a new entry after the specified head.
 * This is good for implementing stacks.
 */
static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head, head->next);
}
```

I'm expecting for the hint to appear like this. (This is from CLion)
[image: CLion]

And this is how it appears on vscode. (which ignores after @at-string)
[image: VSCode]

Are there any way to properly view the documentation hint like this on vscode without modifying the comment to doxygen?? (It may be [kernel-doc](https://docs.kernel.org/doc-guide/kernel-doc.html) style)

[image: VSCodeDoxyGen]

Comment: How does vscode know your comment is not doxygen style? What is the style you're using? You may lookup if there is plugin for parsing that.

Comment: Doxygen style is neat enough and vscode helps you to type a `/***/` above the function and press enter in the middle of the comment. It will generate a comment block according to the parameters.

Comment: Idk what style it is since it's not my code. This code is from linux.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h
may be kernel-doc? I think
https://docs.kernel.org/doc-guide/kernel-doc.html

Comment: It's called [Kernel-doc](https://docs.kernel.org/doc-guide/kernel-doc.html). You may start your serach from the keyword.